# How to remove the new line in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to remove new line in vb .net:

```
Title = Honus Wagner: The Life of Baseball's "Flying Dutchman"

Author = Arthur D. Hittner,  
ListPrice = $35.00

TotalOffers = 0
```

Between the title and author, then ListPrice and TotalOffers
I don't want that new(free) line.
How to remove this new line using vb.net?

refer this code:

```
MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Title", MyXmlNamespaceManager)                                              
ResponseMessage += "Title = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText  
ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

MyXmlNodeList = ItemXmlNode.SelectNodes("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Author", MyXmlNamespaceManager)  
   If IsNothing(MyXmlNodeList) = False Then  
            ResponseMessage += "Author = "  
               For Each MyXmlNode In MyXmlNodeList  
           ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText & ", "  
               Next  
   End If  
ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:ListPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)  
             ResponseMessage += "ListPrice = "  
                  If IsNothing(MyXmlNode) = False Then  
                       ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText  
                  End If  
ResponseMessage += vbCrLf  

MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:Offers/amz:TotalOffers", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
     ResponseMessage += "TotalOffers = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText
```

Comment: MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Title", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "Title = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                         ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

Comment: Refer above code.any error in these code?

Comment: your edit of the question just changed the entire nature of the question. I would suggest you edit again and post the XML formatted. Its bit of a mess. If you do that I will update my answer to something that will work.

Comment: Please Refer the code now..

Comment: please use a stringbuilder instead of a string if you're going to append to it in a loop

Comment: Maybe there's a newline inside the InnerText, have you took a look?
You could try ResponseMessage += "Title = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText.Replace(vbcrlf, "")
Maybe it's vblf

Comment: Can you show what the original XML looks like and what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: softwaresolution have you tried to trim the reponsemessage or the MyXmlNode.InnerText?

Comment: still i didn't get result..Its showing same output like a above output.I cant remove that new line...Any one help?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the replace method on a string.

```
myStringFromMyXmlNode = myStringFromMyXmlNode.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Using `Environment.NewLine` makes sure that wherever your code goes, it will still reliably split on the new line, for example if it's compiled for mono which runs on Linux where the new line is just a carriage return.

Of course, for your example you could simply remove the lines where you add a new line:

```
ResponseMessage += vbCrLf 'remove these lines from your code and the new lines will disappear
```

Comment: Refer the above code..I tried to implement below code                                  Dim myString as String = ""                                                         myString = myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").But its not working..

Comment: See my edit, the variable `myStringFromMyXmlNode` is meant to be replaced with some other variable or property from your code.

Comment: I tried to remove this line ResponseMessage += vbCrLf  ...but still i got same output with new line